# Redirect all emails to a specific address

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email

I 'm new to Magento, and we just did a migration from version 1 to Magento 2.
I would like to define 2 constants variables, one which is the address email for all email related to the backoffice and the second, the email address for all emails sent to clients.

This is for test purpose before the production.

I have no clue where to search. Do they have a general email function for email ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your query related to order creation?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:
https://github.com/redpa2ya/magento2-module-replace-email-recipients

This allow you redirect all recipients email to a specific email.
So it prevents un-expected email to actual customer.